# Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement iso8601>=0.1.9 for DevStack

Tags: python, openstack, pip

My machine operating system is Ubuntu 12.04
I tried to implement the all in one openstack solution for development. But `./stack.sh` did not succeed.
It looks like a package problem for pip. so, I installed iso8601 manually by `sudo apt-get install python-iso8601` and `sudo pip install iso8601`.But the problem remains. 
Here is a shorten message

```
/local/bin/pip install --build=/tmp/pip-build.plxx4 -e /opt/stack/oslo.messaging
Obtaining file:///opt/stack/oslo.messaging
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///opt/stack/oslo.messaging
    [pbr] Reusing existing SOURCES.txt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): oslo.config>=1.2.0 in /opt/stack/oslo.config (from oslo.messaging==1.3.0a9.15.g57ebe0d)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oslo.messaging==1.3.0a9.15.g57ebe0d)
Downloading/unpacking iso8601>=0.1.9 (from oslo.messaging==1.3.0a9.15.g57ebe0d)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement iso8601>=0.1.9 (from oslo.messaging==1.3.0a9.15.g57ebe0d)
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for iso8601>=0.1.9 (from oslo.messaging==1.3.0a9.15.g57ebe0d)
Storing complete log in /home/shisoft/.pip/pip.log
+ exit_trap
+ local r=1
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ exit 1
shisoft@shisoft-HQStackA:~/devstack$ sudo pip install iso8601
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): iso8601 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 ships [`python-iso8601`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-iso8601) version `0.1.4`, whilst in [pipy.org](https://pypi.python.org/) you can find version [`0.1.10`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/0.1.10), which fulfills the requirements of the installer.

Also, the log explicitly says you need to override the installed version using `--upgrade`, so you need to issue:

```
# pip install --upgrade 8601
```

After that, compare the output of:

```
# dpkg -l python-iso8601
```

and:

```
# pip list | grep iso8601
```

Comment: hi, I just tried the first line but it returns `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement 8601` and the version of 8601 is still 0.1.4

Comment: the first line should be `pip install --upgrade iso8601`